# When to use "it" instead of "who"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, who-that

In using a title for a particular function of a person (for example, "supplier", "seller", "buyer", "exporter"), is it proper to use the word "it" and "that" and "itself", instead of "he or she" and "who" when referring to the function?

Examples:

> - The supplier will respond after *it* has received a communication.
> - A seller *that* is interested will follow up the transaction.
> - The buyer *itself* may take on the responsibilty.
> - The exporter must disclose *its* supply capacity.

Comment: When you say "supplier" etc. are you talking about individual people, or about businesses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use “who” vs. “that”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11204/), [Can “that” be used to refer to people?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/47039/), [Is it appropriate to refer to a person of unknown sex by “it”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56567/) [Use of “it” and “its” for people and animals](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/49404/). In fact we have dedicated tags for [*who* vs. *that*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/who-that) and [gender-neutral pronouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-neutral).

Comment: I will be using the term in the manner which is not gender-specific. I will use it to refer to a function or role. "Supplier", for example, is a role that can be acted out by an indivdual human being or by a non-human entity such as a corporation. Thank you very much for your interest to help me.

Answer (score 2):

When *supplier, etc.* refers to a person use *he, she, who, etc.* Otherwise, use *it, that, etc*. In some cases where it's unknown, you might be well off with *they, their, etc.*, but this might not pass muster with some traditionalists.

Comment: Thank you, Noah. In the manner I will be using the terms ("supplier" for example), they will not be gender-specific. They particularly refer to functions or roles. I appreciate your suggestion to pluralize them, but that may not fit well on how I would want the statements, where they are used, to be understood.

Comment: But if the words refer to functions or roles, they refer to people's functions or roles; or those of organisations staffed by people. It sounds **really** odd to use the impersonal *that* (and *it*).

Answer (score 0):

Let’s take *that* first. *That* can introduce a relative clause, regardless of whether the antecedent is human or not, when the relative clause defines the antecedent. Such clauses are variously called ‘defining, ‘restrictive’ or ‘integrated’.  In the sentence ‘A seller that is interested will follow up the transaction’, ‘that is interested’ tells us what kind of seller will follow up the transaction, and so *that* is permissible. *Who* may be also be used.

Whether you use *it* to refer to ‘supplier’, 'buyer' and 'exporter' depends on how you regard them If you see them as some kind of abstraction, then *it* might be possible. If, as seems much more likely, you see them as predominantly human, then *it* won’t do. You then have to choose from *he, she* and *they*. There are obvious difficulties with the first two if you don’t know if the supplier is male or female. In many cases, *they* can refer to a singular antecedent, but it is a little awkward in your examples. The best solution might be to make *supplier*, *buyer* and *exporter* plural, so that you get the sentences:

> The suppliers will respond after they have received a communication.
>
> The buyers themselves may take on the responsibility.
>
> The exporters must disclose their supply capacity.

Comment: Thank you very much, Barrie England. I very much appreciate the comprehensive manner you presented the explanation. I feel much better now with my use of "that" after reading your explanation of its usage. I still have problem, however, with the "it". In the use of the title "supplier" for example, I will use it with reference to a function or role. I feel that it will be awkward for me to pluralize it as I would mean it to refer to a single entity. The role can be acted out by an individual human being or by a single non-human entity such as a corporation.

Comment: The use of _it_ in such a context would be hard to justify.

Comment: Your first sentence is ungrammatical due to a sequence-of-tense error: it must be *receive*, not **received*.  I realize this was in the original, but thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: @tchrist. Not where I live.

Comment: @BarrieEngland You are right: I didn’t see the *have*.

Comment: @tchrist. The present tense is, of course, also possible.

Comment: I read it as "will . . . after it received", which was the problem.

Comment: @Barrie England: Thank you very much for your feedback.